# Kubernetes expose does not work from file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

If I run command

```
kubectl expose deployments/some-app --type=NodePort
```

it works.

If I run command

```
kubectl apply -f expose.yml
```

Where the content of expose.yml is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: some-app
  labels:
    app: some-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: some-app
```

I cannot reach the service.

What is the difference? Why the 2nd approach does not work?

EDIT: Use NodePort in the yml as well

EDIT:
Result of command `kubectl expose deployments/some-app --type=NodePort --dry-run -o yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: some-app
    type: spring-app
  name: some-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    name: some-app
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your expose command you use `--type=NodePort`, but in svc `type=ClusterIP`. If you want to see what expose command created then add `--dry-run --o yaml` at the end of the command. You should see like following.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: some-app
  name: some-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: some-app
  type: NodePort
```

NB: After discussion in comment, you need to ensure `app: some-app` exists on pod leve.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot replacing ClusterIP in the yml before I posted the question. In my case it is the same if I use NodePort or ClusterIP, because I tested both of them, calling the pod from browser and from other pod as well.

Comment: what is output of  ```kubectl expose deployments/some-app --type=NodePort --dry-run -o yaml ``` ?

Comment: Added to question

Comment: In your pod level  ```app: some-app``` exists? In expose commange check ```name: some-app``` selector. aslo, can you check adding targetPort: 8080 in your yaml file?

Comment: I add app label to every deployment. However changing the selector from `app: some-app` to `name: some-app` fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the yaml version of the Service you created using this command:

```
kubectl expose deployments/some-app --type=NodePort
```

With:

```
kubectl get service <your-service> -o yaml
```

And then compare both of it, the one you created using `yaml` and the one you created using `expose` command.

Comment: `event-gateway         ClusterIP   10.109.67.190    <none>        8080/TCP         69s`
`event-gateway         ClusterIP   10.104.240.155   <none>        8080/TCP         3s`
First is with the yml, 2nd is the command line. It looks the same. I also checked the difference of the result of command `kubectl describe service some-app`, and they were also the same.